# Windows API for the location of Hiberfil.sys

Tags: winapi, wmi

Does anybody know if there is a Windows API to return the location of the hiberfil.sys ?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried to google it? There's a thread that might be helpful: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/b5baa5bf-bdb2-4c9e-8795-1441f59700a0/

Comment: If your program is dependent on the location of hyberfil.sys then You're Doing It Wrong. Hyberfil is a system critical component. Do not touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Hiberfil.sys is created when you enable hibernation and have hibernated your computer at least once. Its location can be determined like any other file: by directing the OS to search for it. Its usual location is in the root of your system drive, which is usually C:. This working powershell script was found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/435826f4-9b3c-4783-afa3-b1c1bbc554dd). See the link for the full script, but this is the core:

```
gwmi cim_datafile -filter "path='\\'" | ? {$_.name -match 'hiberfil.sys'} or

gwmi -Query "Associators of {Win32_Directory.Name='C:\'} Where ResultClass=CIM_DataFile" | ? {$_.name -match 'hiberfil.sys'}
```

Also helpful, Karl. E. Peterson's API reference:
http://vb.mvps.org/samples/apixref.asp

He also has made available for download some sample code, [zipped](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/FileInfo/) up. Hope this helps...

Comment: There is no guarantee that the hibernation file will be called `hiberfil.sys` in future versions of Windows.